# How to connect to RPCPORT=9332 via LAN

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, daemon

- I edited litecoin.conf file...

To this:

```
testnet=0
rcpuser=user
rpcpassowrd=pass
rpcport=9332
server=1
```

I use minerd with litecoind and when I try to connect to the local machine 127.0.0.1:9332 everything work fine. When I try to connect another workers from the LAN it cant connect to litecoind.

When I scan the port of the machine running litecoind, the port 9332 is closed.

How can I remote connect to the litecoind daemon via LAN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to allow connections from any machine, use:

```
rpcallowip=*
```

If you want to allow connections from one specific IP address, put that IP address instead of `*`:

```
rpcallowip=192.168.0.101
```

You can have as many of these lines as you like.  Use one for each IP address you want to allow.  And wildcards are also allowed:

```
rpcallowip=192.168.0.*
rcpallowip=10.*
rcpallowip=192.168.*.100
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but the daemon is only accessible via 127.0.0.1  If I try to connect via LAN it is refused.

Comment: Does it work with rpcallowip=*?  If not, maybe it's a firewall issue.  Do you know which kind of firewall you have on the machine running bitcoind?  Check netstat -l output on the bitcoind machine.  You should see that it's listen on 0.0.0.0:8332 if you supplied any kind of rpcallowip argument.  When I try to connect remotely without any rpcallowip argument I get "error: couldn't connect to server".  If I try connecting from an IP that's different than the rpcallowip address I see "error: server returned HTTP error 403".

Comment: It is working now! I forgot that I had to setup tunneling. Thank's!

Comment: bitcoind supports JSON-RPC over SSL connections (see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon), so you don't need to set up a separate tunnel if you don't want to

Comment: Thank's now I understand how to make it work properly!